# dataset is undefined - this in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use the `dataset` rule to get the data-attribute of an element in Vue. I'm doing it like so:

```
<ul id="filter">
        <li><a class="filter-item" v-on:click="filterItems" data-letter="a" href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a class="filter-item" v-on:click="filterItems" data-letter="b" href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a class="filter-item" v-on:click="filterItems" data-letter="c" href="#">C</a></li>
      </ul>


var titleFilter = new Vue({
      el: '#filter',
      methods: {
        filterItems: function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var whichFilterItem = this.dataset.letter;
          console.log(whichFilterItem);
        }
      }
    });
```

In my console I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'letter' of undefined

I'm referencing MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

It says to simply use `dataset` and "get the property by the part of the attribute name after data-" but when I do that it doesn;t work.

My initial thought was that it had to do with the event target and it was actually getting the `<li>`. When I console log `e.target` it gives me the anchor tag. which is correct

Comment: You have to add dataset to the vue data.

Comment: When you do `this.dataset`, you're trying to get the `dataset` property of the vue instance. You don't have this data on the instance.

Comment: If you wish to pick the value from the clicked element, you can do this: `e.target.dataset.letter`. This should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `this.dataset`, you're trying to get the dataset property of the vue instance's data. You don't have this data on the instance.

You're trying to get a property of the clicked element. You can access the element trough the event variable.

Like this:

```
var titleFilter = new Vue({
      el: '#filter',
      methods: {
        filterItems: function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var whichFilterItem = e.target.dataset.letter;
          alert(whichFilterItem);
        }
      }
    });
```

As an addition, [Vue accepts modifiers on its listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

You're using `e.preventDefault()` inside the function. You can ignore that if you use the modifier on the `v-on:click` directive like this:

```
v-on:click.prevent="filterItems"
```

Comment: This works but I'd definitely suggest a better approach to OP as well. Also, `currentTarget` instead of `target` would be safer (in case there's actually children in the real markup).

Comment: Yeah, I'd not use this myself. The best way is to use v-model, I don't know how to apply that to anchor tags tho

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of: https://jsfiddle.net/vmor46oe/1/ which is ultimately where I think OP will end up.